# Linking Css to html in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to build a website in python and flask however my CSS is not loading I don't see anything wrong with my code and I've tried the same code snippet from a few different sites.

My Link:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename= 'css/style.css') }}">
```

File structure as below:

[image: File Structure]

> Error: 127.0.0.1 - - [16/Sep/2021 20:18:34] "GET /static/css/style.css
> HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Comment: either you need to put the file inside `/static/css/xyz.css` or have the folder pointer in your link to `/styles/xyz.css`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have written the path to CSS file wrong. It should be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename= 'styles/style.css') }}">
```

you have written `css/style.css`. According to the file structure you have attached, it should be `styles/style.css`.

Answer (score 0):

What is the actual directory your stylesheet is in? I suspect it isn't in /static/css/ under the root directory of your app. This should work if your css file is in /static/css/:

```
<link href="/static/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```